# How to get all input values on a table TR (by ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, frontend

how are you?

How can I get all values of a inputs inside a one TR in a table? I'd find examples, with not for a specific row (with ID) 
I have this table:

```
<table>
   <tr id="a">
      <td><input id="a_01" value="the value of a_01"></td>
      <td><input id="a_02" value="the value of a_02"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="b">
      <td><input id="b_01" value="the value of b_01"></td>
      <td><input id="b_02" value="the value of b_02"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

For example: i'm triying to get all value inputs of a tr with id="b".

Thanks a lot for yout help!

Comment: This is one of those questions where you're honestly better off just reading about introductory jquery than asking it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector to target the elements. To do so, you don't need jQuery, since you can use the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) functions:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Radio input value
  var value = document.querySelector('input[name="idvalue"]:checked').value;

  // Here's the selector for the input elements
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#' + value + ' input');
  
  // You can iterate the result and use the element values
  elements.forEach(e => {console.log(e.id + ': ' + e.value);});
});
```

```html
<table>
   <tr id="a">
      <td><input id="a_01" value="the value of a_01"></td>
      <td><input id="a_02" value="the value of a_02"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="b">
      <td><input id="b_01" value="the value of b_01"></td>
      <td><input id="b_02" value="the value of b_02"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="idvalue" id="radioa" value="a" checked /><label for="radioa">Show values for #a</label>
  <input type="radio" name="idvalue" id="radiob" value="b" /><label for="radiob">Show values for #b</label>
</div>
<button>Show Values of selected #id</button>
```

If you *really* *really* need t do it in [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can use the same selector to target the elements: `$("#b input")`.

I suggest you further read about [selectors](/questions/tagged/selectors). [Here's the MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors).

Comment: Thanks @Niche for your help. I'm a backend dev and I'm having some troubles with a front :( jajaja.
Can I pass a var inside ('#b input') like ('#'+id`+'input')? I'm getting some errors (Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#6640e122-2d43-4bce-b1f4-96bb8b68476a' is not a valid selector) ....

Comment: Yes, you can use dynamic values for the selector, since `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` expect a string parameter for the selector value. I updated my example to include dynamic selectors.